# likebox height in Opera under Android

Tags: android, facebook, mobile, opera, facebook-likebox

I've built Likebox to one of our webpage and it's working well in most browsers, except in Opera mobile browser under Adroid OS (I didn't checked Opera under iOS).

The likebox contains stream, and in Opera mobile browser it doesn't use the "overflow: hidden" style, and its stream flows the elements under the likebox.
http://a5.hu/auto/mercedes-benz-g63-amg-6x6-hatkerek-meghajtassal-video (right panel, 4-5th box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by updateing Opera browser on Android.